# django: why do i cannot store twitter.Twitter object into session

Tags: django, session, object, twitter

I created a twitter.Twitter object, but cannot store it into session. Following is my code.

```
t = twitter.Twitter(auth=twitter.OAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, 
    oauth_token, oauth_secret))    
request.session['t'] = t
```

but if I store a string like

```
request.session['t'] = 't'
```

it works, why? because the twitter#Twitter object is not a serializable object? How can I avoid authenticating each time when I need a twitter#Twitter object? Following is the django trace.

```
Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'myproj.myapp']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  178.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  36.                 request.session.save()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/file.py" in save
  121.                     os.write(output_file_fd, self.encode(session_data))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in encode
  93.         pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twitter-1.9.0-py2.6.egg/twitter/api.py" in __call__
  173.         return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twitter-1.9.0-py2.6.egg/twitter/api.py" in _handle_response
  198.                 raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)

Exception Type: TwitterHTTPError at /tool/log_in/
Exception Value:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you guessed, you can only store [pickleable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickle) objects.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/#technical-details)

> The session dictionary should accept any pickleable Python object. See the pickle module for more information.

Comment: Thank you Javier, but what is the workaround, How can I avoid authenticating each time when I need a twitter#Twitter object? sorry, seems this is another question.

Comment: store enough data to rebuild the object.  I don't know the details of the Twitter object, but there should be some serializable Oauth keys